# How to watch for localstorage changes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is it possible to use $watch to monitor changes to localStorage?

I have a factory to make setting/getting a little simpler

```
.factory('$localstorage', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
        set: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = value;
        },

        get: function(key, defaultValue) {
            return $window.localStorage[key] || defaultValue;
        },

        setObject: function(key, value) {
            $window.localStorage[key] = JSON.stringify(value);
        },

        getObject: function(key) {
            return JSON.parse($window.localStorage[key] || '{}');
        }
    }
}]);
```

In my controller I have

```
.controller('CodesCtrl', function($scope, $localstorage) {
    $scope.codes = $localstorage.getObject('codes');
    ...
```

In another controller I'm adding to local storage. I'd like to render the changes as soon as localStorage changes.

I've seen a few SO posts that use things like ngStorage but ideally I'd like to avoid that.

Is it possible? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: overload `localStorage.getItem` and `localStorage.setItem` with your own methods.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can create a $watch function that returns anything you want. When it changes, your $watch will run.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
  return $localstorage.getObject('codes');
}, function(newCodes, oldCodes){
  $scope.codes = newCodes;
});
```

Make sure to do performance testing on that. This function will be called a lot.

---

A better way would be to use events and only update `codes` when necessary.

Controller A:

```
var codes = updateCodesAndStoreInLocalStorage(); // <That part's up to you
$rootScope.$emit('codesUpdated', codes);
```

Controller B:

```
$rootScope.$on('codesUpdated', function(event, codes){
  $scope.codes = codes; //Rely on localStorage for "storage" only, not for communication.
});
```

Comment: Note that if you go with a watch, the watch handler is not called immediately when the value in localStorage changes. Since Angular only compares old values with new values (dirty checking) in a $digest, the watch handler will only be called if a $digest occurs. Most user initiated actions will start a $digest (i.e. ng-click) but if you're expecting things to just happen automatically, you need to be aware of how watch handlers are called.

Comment: Angular's wrappers for things like $localstorage and $timeout exist to trigger $digest cycles when they've been used, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: can you please elaborate more on your 2nd way . can't get it clearly, i am also want to implement like James

Comment: Sure. Whenever you save something to localstorage, it's in response to an event (e.g. a button being clicked, or some text entered into an input field). When that event occurs you can $emit() an event. It's like announcing to the app that something has happened. In this case, we're announcing that some data was saved (using an arbitrary name: 'codesUpdated').
Elsewhere in the app, in some other controller(s), and prior to $emitting the event, we use $on() to say: "When 'codesUpdated' happens, run this code in response". That code might update the UI, or perhaps save the data to a server.